# Why I can't write to log trace to file using nlog?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, logging, nlog

I started to learn how to configurate the nlog in .net core web API application. And read some tutorials, and have tried to implement the realization from an official tutorial from github

1) Create `nlog.confiq` xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  autoReload="true" 
  internalLogLevel="Trace" 
  internalLogFile="D:/Projects/appstore2/AppStore/AppStore.DataAccessLayer/Logs/InnerLog.txt">

<extensions>
  <!--enable NLog.Web for ASP.NET Core-->
  <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
</extensions>

<variable name="PathToFile" value="D:/Projects/appstore2/AppStore/AppStore.DataAccessLayer/Logs"/>

<!-- define various log targets -->
<targets async="true">    
  <!-- write logs to file -->
  <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="D:/Projects/appstore2/AppStore/AppStore.DataAccessLayer/Logs/${shortdate}_log.txt" layout="${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} ${message}"/>

</targets>

<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" final="true"/>
</rules>
```

2) configure my Programm.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();

        try
        {
            logger.Debug("init main");
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //NLog: catch setup errors
            logger.Fatal(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
            NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
        }
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
            })
            .UseNLog();
}
```

3) change the json file and add the next code:

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Trace",
        "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
}
```

4) after this, I create the private field in the controller class

```
 private readonly ILogger<UserController> _logger;

    public UserController(ILogger<UserController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

and use this logger in try/catch

```
 catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning(ex, "LOG WARNING HELLOOOO");
        _logger.LogTrace(ex, "LOG TRACE HELLOOOO");
        return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
    }
```

but when I create the error situation, I don't have the `LogTrace` info in my file

> 2019-08-20 19:52:21.9065 INFO Executing action method AppStore.Web.Controllers.UserController.AddAsync (AppStore.Web) - Validation state: Valid
>   Blockquote
>
> 2019-08-20 19:52:22.2795 WARN LOG WARNING HELLOOOO
>
> 2019-08-20 19:52:22.2817 INFO Executed action method
>   AppStore.Web.Controllers.UserController.AddAsync (AppStore.Web),
>   returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NotFoundObjectResult in
>   373.2219ms.

why I can't see the trace information, what I did wrong in configuration or need to do other realization. I tested log -error, info, warn, fatal but only trace doesn't save in my file.

Comment: Tried to the example application here (very similar to your example), and LogTrace works just fine: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/tree/dev/examples/ASP.NET%20Core%202/Visual%20Studio%202017/ASP.NET%20Core%202%20-%20VS2017 Maybe try adding `logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace)` in case your LogLevel-setting is not working because you have an environment-specific AppSettings.json file (Ex. appsettings.Development.json)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Configure appsettings.json](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2#5-configure-appsettingsjson) indicates:

> The Logging configuration specified in appsettings.json overrides any
>   call to SetMinimumLevel. So either remove "Default": or adjust it
>   correctly to your needs.

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Trace",
            "Microsoft": "Information"
        }
    }
}
```

> Remember to also update any environment specific configuration to
>   avoid any surprises. Ex appsettings.Development.json

You need to change `Logging` section both in `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json`.

For `appsettings.Development.json`, you could check `appsettings.json` or open the project folder to find and edit it.

Comment: I delete "Default": "Trace" and it doesn't help me, to my regret, I cant see the trace log. I don't have any json app setting files in my app. And I delete all Logging setting json, it doesn't help me too.

Comment: @Andrey Have you checked the `appsettings.Development.json` in folder? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where this development file place. I delete from both of them and it works fine thank you, I wrote the trace!)